# sql server external tools logging errorlog

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 I installed some external tools and then removed them.  Somehow I am getting this error in the error logs.  How can I remove this queue?

```
The activated proc '[LakeSideLockLogger].[_LakeSide_DbTools_LockMonitorEvents]' running on queue 'msdb.LakeSideLockLogger._LakeSide_DbTools_LockQueue' output the following:  'Could not find stored procedure 'LakeSideLockLogger._LakeSide_DbTools_LockMonitorEvents'.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the link below to  uninstall:

http://www.sqlsolutions.com/products/sql-deadlock-detector/Uninstall.html